# sorting a multi column data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data pool like below
Marks 1 and Marks 2 are in percentages

```
Subject  Marks1  Marks2

ABC      45       55
CDE      34       66
DHD      54       46
XYZ      35       65
YXS      56       44
YDT      88       12
```

I have plotted the graph but i have a problem with the order of the data ie i need the graph to be oriented in such a way that marks1 should be in ascending order ie 34 to be the first bar then the rest

the code i have written is

```
n.data = ddply(c.data,.(subject), transform, pos = cumsum(value) - 0.5*value)

plot = ggplot(n.data, aes(x = subject, y = value)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = value, y = pos), size = 3, face="bold", colour="white") +

    labs(fill="")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems to get your code running. First, I think, you missed the part where you melt your data from the data you've shown to get `c.data`:

```
c.data <- melt(dat, id.var="Subject")
```

Second, your `subject` should be `Subject`:

Third, since you pass both `x` and `y` arguments to aesthetics, you should do `stat = "identity"`. Otherwise, you'll get a warning because the default argument is `stat = "bin"` .

Finally, to order the plot in the way you require, you'll have to set your `Subject` factor levels accordingly. So, here's the full code:

```
# set factor levels
dat$Subject <- factor(dat$Subject, levels = dat$Subject[order(dat$Marks1)])

require(reshape2)
c.data <- melt(dat, id.var="Subject")

require(plyr)
n.data = ddply(c.data,.(Subject), transform, pos = cumsum(value) - 0.5*value)

require(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(n.data, aes(x = Subject, y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "#000000", aes(fill = variable)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = value, y = pos), size = 3, face="bold", colour="white") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF", "#000000")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0,100, by = 10)) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(),
          axis.text.x=element_text (angle=60,hjust=1,colour="black"),
          axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
    labs(fill="") + scale_colour_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you arun for your instant reply but the error is just continuing again i mean there is no difference in the graph produced even after the necessary changes the graph data works fine till the ddply function is applied and it goes back after the ddply function is applied

Comment: With the data you've shown above, the code I've shown, as you can see, works as you wanted (iiuc). So, you'll have to show a data where this doesn't work. I can't debug until then.

Comment: n.data showing error so i need to fix n.data but i am unable to can you please help me with this